# How to leave existing class attribute on image element - now it is being moved to a generated enclosing span

Tags: ckeditor5

**Background:** Trying to use ckeditor5 as a replacement for my homegrown editor in a non-invasive way - meaning without changing my edited content or its class definitions. Would like to have WYSIWYG in the editor. Using django_ckeditor_5 as a base with my own ckeditor5 build that includes ckedito5-inspector and my extraPlugins and custom CSS. This works nicely.

**Problem**:  When I load the following HTML into ClassicEditor (edited textarea.value):

```
<p>Text with inline image: <img class="someclass" src="/media/uploads/some.jpeg"></p>
```

in the editor view area, browser-inspection of the DOM shows:

```
... 
<p>Text with an inline image: 
<span class="image-inline ck-widget someclass ck-widget_with-resizer" contenteditable="false">
<img src="/media/uploads/some.jpeg">
<div class="ck ck-reset_all ck-widget__resizer ck-hidden">
<div ...></div></span></p>
...
```

Because the "someclass" class has been removed from  and moved to the enclosing  class attributes, my stylesheets are not able to size this image element as they would appear before editing.

If, within the ckeditor5 view, I edit the  element using the browser inspector 'by hand' and add back `class="someclass"` to the image,  ckeditor5 displays my page as I'd expect it with "someclass" and with the editing frame/tools also there. Switching to source-editing and back shows the class="someclass" on the  and keeps it there after switching back to document editing mode.

(To get all this, I enabled the GeneralHtmlSupport plugin in the editor config with all allowed per instructions, and that seems to work fine.)  I also added the following simple plugin:

```
export default class Extend extends Plugin {
    static get pluginName() {
    return 'Extend';
    }
    #updateSchema() {
        const schema = this.editor.model.schema;
        schema.extend('imageInline', {
            allowAttributes: ['class']
        });
    }
    init() {
        const editor = this.editor;
        this.#updateSchema();
    }
}
```

to extend the imageInline model hoping that would make the Image plugin keep this class attribute.

This is the part where I need some direction on how to proceed - what should be added/modified in the Image Plugin or in my Extend plugin to keep the class attribute with the  element while editing - basically to fulfill the WYSIWYG desire?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Mr. Nose Tothegrind found two solutions after digging through ckeditor5 code, here's the first one. This extension Plugin restores all image attributes that are collected by GeneralHtmlSupport. It can be imported and added to a custom ckeditor5 build `app.js` file by adding `config.extraPlugins = [ Extend ];` before the editor.create(...) statement.

```
    import Plugin from             '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';
    import GeneralHtmlSupport from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support/src/generalhtmlsupport';
    
    export default class Extend extends Plugin {
        static get pluginName() {
        return 'Extend';
        }
        static get requires() {
        return [ GeneralHtmlSupport ];
        }
        
        init() {
            const editor = this.editor;
            this.#setupConversion();
        }
    
        #setupConversion() {
        const editor = this.editor;
        const t = editor.t;
        const conversion = editor.conversion;
    
            conversion.for ( 'editingDowncast' ).add( // Custom conversion helper
                dispatcher =>
                dispatcher.on( 'attribute:htmlAttributes:imageInline', (evt, data, { writer, mapper }) => {
                    const imageContainer = mapper.toViewElement(data.item);
                    const imageElement = imageContainer.getChild(0);
                    if ( data.attributeNewValue !== null ) {
                        const newValue = data.attributeNewValue;
                        if ( newValue.classes ) {
                            writer.setAttribute('class', newValue.classes.join(' '), imageElement);
                        }
                        if ( newValue.attributes ) {
                            for (const name of Object.keys(newValue.attributes)) {
                                writer.setAttribute( name, newValue.attributes[name], imageElement);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        writer.removeAttribute('class', imageElement);
                    }
                })
            );
        }a
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following version does not rely on GeneralHtmlSupport but creates an imageClassAttribute model element and uses that to convert only the image class attribute and place it on the imageInline model view widget  element.

```
import Plugin from         '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';

export default class Extend extends Plugin {
    static get pluginName() {
    return 'Extend';
    }
    
    #updateSchema() {
        const schema = this.editor.model.schema;

        schema.register( 'imageClassAttribute', {
             isBlock: false,
             isInline: false,
             isObject: true,
             isSelectable: false,
             isContent: true,
             allowWhere: 'imageInline',
        });
                         
        schema.extend('imageInline', {
            allowAttributes: ['imageClassAttribute' ]
        });
    }

    init() {
        const editor = this.editor;
        this.#updateSchema();
        this.#setupConversion();
    }

    #setupConversion() {
    const editor = this.editor;
    const t = editor.t;
    const conversion = editor.conversion;

        conversion.for( 'upcast' )
            .attributeToAttribute({
                view: 'class',
                model: 'imageClassAttribute'
            });

        conversion.for( 'dataDowncast' )
            .attributeToAttribute({
                model: 'imageClassAttribute',
                view: 'class'
            });
        
        conversion.for ( 'editingDowncast' ).add( // Custom conversion helper
            dispatcher =>
            dispatcher.on( 'attribute:imageClassAttribute:imageInline', (evt, data, { writer, consumable, mapper }) => {
                if ( !consumable.consume(data.item, evt.name) ) {
                    return;
                }
                const imageContainer = mapper.toViewElement(data.item);
                const imageElement = imageContainer.getChild(0);
                if ( data.attributeNewValue !== null ) {
                    writer.setAttribute('class', data.attributeNewValue, imageElement);
                } else {
                    writer.removeAttribute('class', imageElement);
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```